# android - saving data to firebase is saved with alphabet keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, proguard, android-proguard

my data is saved to firebase this way:

```
a: "Tom"
b: "26"
...
```

I know that in order to save it with the correct keys ("mName" instead of "a", "mAge" instead of "b" and so on) I have to add the next lines to my proguard according to the documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard

```
# Add this global rule
-keepattributes Signature

# This rule will properly ProGuard all the model classes in
# the package com.yourcompany.models. Modify to fit the structure
# of your app.
-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** {
 *;
}
```

my questions is:

1. Assuming that my package name is **com.testing**, should the added lines look like these?

   -keepattributes Signature

   -keepclassmembers class com.testing.models.** {
      *;
     }

OR the second line should be without the "models"? like this:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.testing.** {
```

2. Moreover, if I have only 1 global class named **Data** that I save to firebase, can I just keep these class members specifically? or I must act as shown above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it will look like this

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keepclassmembers class com.testing.models.** { *; }
```

If you have only one model class called Data, add the following lines instead

```
-keepattributes Signature

-keep class com.testing.models.Data { *; }
```

Comment: thanks! and if I want to keep the class members of 1 class only? Is there any option to do so?